# Function executes either the key is there or not in dictionary.get in python 2.7

Tags: python, dictionary

I am working with dictionaries in Python and I am searching for a value using:

```
my_dictionary_object.get("key")
```

As we all know if the key is missing in dictionary, it will return `None` object. 
So to save extra line and to make my code more interesting I am trying:

```
def my_function():
    '''do some calculations'''
    return missing_value_from_dictionary
```

Now here is the fun part; when I do

```
my_dictionary_object.get("key", my_function())
```

it executes the function whether the key is missing or not so I thought let's remove the brackets and I did:

```
my_dictionary_object.get("key", my_function)
```

and *(just in case)*

```
my_dictionary_object.get("key", lambda: my_function())
```

but the one without lambda didn't execute *(because it was never called)* same happened with the one with lambda.

**TL;DR**

**My question is why is the function get executed if the key is present in the dictionary?**

Is it something that I am doing wrong or something I am missing here?

Comment: Because *you called the function*. The arguments get's evaluated before the `.get` function executes. The second parameter gets a *default value*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In: `my_dictionary_object.get("key", my_function())` the execution looks something like:

- Evaluate the first argument ("key")
- Evaluate the second argument which is an expression: `my_function()`. So let's call the function, and use the return value in its place. Very much like in: `a = my_function()`, python would call the function and put the returned value in its place.
- Call the `mydictionary_object.get(..)` with the above two evaluated arguments.

In other words, `dictionary.get("key", default)` will simply return the 2nd argument if the key doesn't exist. If it is a lambda, lambda is returned. A lambda is an object. Note that in `.get("key", my_function())`, `my_function()` is not technically the second argument. The resultant value returned as a result of execution of that function is the second argument -- which explains where you're wrong, hopefully.

---

What you are looking for is actually captured in another container called [`defaultdict`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/collections.html?highlight=ordereddict#collections.defaultdict).

What you'd do is:

```
from collections import defaultdict

my_dictionary_object = defaultdict(my_function)  # my_function should not take any argument.
my_dictionary_object["non-existing-key"]         # Magic happens, see below.
```

What happens is, if the key (=x) doesn't exist, `my_function` is called without any arguments and the dictionary is updated with the value returned by the function against the key (=x). Something like:

```
if "key" not in dictionary:
    dictionary["key"] = my_function()
    return dictionary["key"]
```

Comment: Thanks to you i understand why my code is not working. :)

Comment: Note that __using a `defaultdict` will yield a very different behaviour__ : trying to access a missing key in a `defaultdict` does __create__ the key in the dict (while `dict.get(<missing_key>)` doesn't).

Comment: Yes, I think I have mentioned that in my answer. Probably should've called that out explicitly, though.